# Create class from string in c++ to avoid large switch statement?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am refactoring a C++ application to make better use of polymorphism. I have a large factory method that instantiates the proper object based on an Enum. Rather than have a large switch statement, is there a way to have a lookup table that maps from the values of the Enum to classes that I could then use to create the proper object?

Comment: As Kerrek SB answer, When you want to pass an type, you can write an template function, and pass the template function specialization with the type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use a map:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(); };

struct Factory
{
    enum Types { ThingA, WidgetB, GadgetC };

    typedef Base * (*MakerFunction)();

    static std::map<Types, MakerFunction> makers;

    static std::unique_ptr<Base> create(Types t)
    {
        return { makers[t]() };
    }
};
```

Now for every object derived from `Base` you just have to insert a suitable creation function into the map `Factory::makers`.

Example:

```
struct Thing : Base
{
    static Base * create() { return new Thing; }
};

// somewhere

Factory::makers[Factory::ThingA] = &Thing::create;
```

(Personally, I'd probably use `unique_ptr`s in all the interfaces, and maybe have some sort of self-registration mechanism with an auxiliary class that does the registration in a constructor. You'd also want to add checks that the enum value is actually in the map. You could also use this approach for string-keyed class selection.)

Comment: If the enums are ascending integers as they usually are, you can use an array rather than a map.

Comment: +1 I was writing a similar answer but you beat me to it (as usual :p). **However** the runtime performance of such a map will be worse than a `switch` (the latter being optimized into a jump table) so I wouldn't really advise that, especially since the difference between setting up the map and writing the switch is negligible from the developer's POV. Now if the key wasn't an `enum` but a `string` (or any other non-switchable type), a map would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: @syam: Sure; the advantage of the map is that you can add new classes to the game without touching the factory code -- even at runtime if you were so inclined.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah right, I didn't take such considerations into account, I assumed the set of classes was fixed. (since OP uses an `enum` in the first place, he needs at the very least to modify the `enum` definition in order to extend his factory). But you're right too of course, a map is much more modular.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a map from enum to classes, but you can have one to factory functions. Something like

```
typedef BaseClass* (*Maker_t)();

template <typename T>
BaseClass* Maker() { return new T(); }

std::map<MyEnum, Maker_t> makers = {{CLASS_A, Maker<ClassA>}, ...};

BaseClass* b = makers[enumValue]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Write yourself a template factory function, e.g.:

```
enum EnumType {
     Derived1,
     Derived2,
     ...
};

template <class T>
MyBase* CreateSomething() {
    return new T();
}
```

Then declare a lookup table like this:

```
typedef MyBase*(*factory_t)();
factory_t factories[] = {
     &CreateSomething<Derived1>,
     &CreateSomething<Derived2>,
     ...
}
```

And invoke like this:

```
EnumType my_val = ...;
MyBase* b = factories[my_val]();
```

I'd suggest using unique_ptr instead of raw pointers for safety, I've only used raw pointers above to keep the example simple. Same goes for std::array or std::vector instead of the  array.

If your enum values are spares, a std::map may be more appropriate, but with a normal enum (contiguous, starting from zero) it's unnecessary overhead.